# How to model such that a drill through for Order suppliers having M:1 relation with Order fact table can be configured?

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, star-schema

I have product dimension, date dimension, Order fact.

There is 1:M relation between dimension and fact.

This is a simple star schema.

In Order fact the OrderNumber column is unique.

I want to introduce a new table into the model called Order suppliers. This table has OrderNumber, Supplier name Supplier location, Supplier code. In this table one OrderNumber can have multiple rows (suppliers).

How best to add this table into the model such that user can drill through from the Order fact visual to the page showing Order supplier details.

Should I extract and make a common dimension containing Order number that connects to Order and Order Supplier table?

Comment: The standard way to model this type of scenario is to have a group bridge table between your fact table and your supplier dimension. Kimball provides a number of examples of this in the “Data Warehouse Toolkit”

Comment: Isn't group brige used to solve M:N scenario? Mine is a 1:M scenario. 1 order can have many suppliers.

Comment: It’s used to model having multiple records in a dimension table related to a single fact record - which I think is what you’ve described?

Comment: AFAIK a bridge table is useful only when establishing a Many to many relation

Comment: How else do you expect to link a single fact record to multiple records in a dimension table? If you read the Kimball book you’ll see multiple examples of this pattern. Having read these, if you think it’s not relevant to your use case can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should add also the **ProductID** in the **OrderSupplier** table and also connect it to dim Product. After this is done, you should create something like this model:
[image: here]

If you do not have productID, you will get returned a combination of Product and Supplier (if you have 2 products and 2 suppliers in one complete order, you will get 4 rows - product A with suppl A, product A with suppl B, product B with suppl A, and product B with suppl B). I hope this helps, I tried with sample data. I can send you the file and dataset if you want.

Comment: As OrderNumber is unique in Orders table, there cannot be a situation where same order has 2 products.

Comment: There is no ProductId in Supplier table

Answer (score 0):

Then I think you can keep dim Orders as a dimension that will connect fact Orders and Orders Supplier, or do this modification:

[image]

The fact table will be on the one side, and OrderSupplier on the many side, which will allow to drill-through by ordernumber to see suppliers for each order.

Comment: But isn't this against the principles of star schema

Comment: Yeah, this is no more star schema. But really for 'OrderSupplier' table 'fact Orders' is a dimension. And the filter direction - both, is to enable to see the Price (or any other amount) filtered by supplier. You can test with your real data to verify the data returned is correct.

Comment: Is there a better/standard pattern/way to model such scenario?